# Android inAppPurchase

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I use the library https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3
for my test project. All works fine.
Now i have installed my test app on 2 different device but the **same google account.**
The test App is only in a **internal test track on my play store account.**
Now i have bought on the first device the full version which works fine.
Then on the second device i want to check my purchase by calling the method billingProcessor.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle() which returns information from google server not from my apps local cache but nevertheless i get zero entrys from the returned purchaseList array on the second device. The first device where i bought the product of course returns me the valid purchase.

> Note

Iˋm checking the result from the service method billingService.getPurchases(., ., ., .) which returns a bundle object which has a method bundle.getStringArrayList(.)

Thatˋs really strange.
Can some body say me why i dont get the same purchaseList array returned on both of my device.
Again both device have installed the same app version from google play store and both device have the same google play store account.

**Thanks very much in advance for your help.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue happens some time in test Environment. just clear play store data from the second phone. then check using `billingService.getPurchases()` you will get all purchase details.

Comment: Thank you for saving my golden time. It's really helpful for me.

Comment: Not at all. Have released today a app that has the same problem. Works only if you clear the cache in the play store app or use the command **adb shell pm clear com.android.vending**